# Ionic 2 - How to style the navbar

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

**THE SITUATION**:

I need to style the navbar of my Ionic 2 app.

I found contradictory informations.

It seems before you could do something like this:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar primary>
```

But not anymore..

In my case I need to give a background and modify the color of the text.

I managed to style the background color by modifying this class: `toolbar-background`

```
.toolbar-background {

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left 0%, left 100%, from(#00aaff), to(#009eb9));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00aaff, 0%, #009eb9, 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00aaff 0%, #009eb9 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00aaff 0%, #009eb9 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
```

But I didn't managed to change the text color.

I have tried with the following classes:

```
toolbar-text-color   toolbar-active-color
```

**CODEPEN**:

https://codepen.io/johnnyfittizio/pen/xRXJWd

**THE QUESTION**:

What is proper way to style the navbar?

Side question:

The best practice is to style it in the app.scss right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize these are the css elements you need to change in order to style the navbar:

- `toolbar-background` -> for the navbar background
- `toolbar-title` -> for the navbar title
- `bar-button` -> for the menu buttons

For the changes to be global I have applied the style in the **app.scss** file

If you have updates please edit this or make a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
.toolbar-background is the default class provided in inspect element
```

after trying to access this class and apply the color

for example

```
 .toolbar-background-md{
    background: gray;
    }
.toolbar-background-ios{
    background: gray;
    }
```

**update**

to update the title in the nav bar

```
.toolbar-title-md{
        color: white;
        font-family: roboto;
    }
.toolbar-title-ios{
        color: white;
        font-family: roboto;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. As you can see I have already managed to style the background color. I need to know how to style the text color as well. And in general could be nice to know the proper way to style the navbar in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use property "color". If you not change color the full aplicattion, not necessary change the sccs
Ex:

```js
 <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="btn_logout()">Logout</button>
```